Vacuous truth in non-classical logics
Does the notion of a vacuous truth exist in non-classical logics as well? I'm thinking of logics inspired by intuitionism, which assign great importance to constructive proofs.


Does the notion of a vacuous truth exist in non-classical logics as well?

The short answer is yes, ex falso quodlibet does hold constructively (constructively as in no axioms at all, neither classical nor intuitionistic or anyway anti-classical).  Namely, P -> Q constructively means "given a proof of P, we get a proof of Q", so it is not the truth-table method of course, but it remains the case that given a proof of False anything follows: False in type-theoretic terms is an (the, actually) empty propositional type.

I see. Thank you!

You reference the BHK interpretation of Intuitionistic Logic. You’re correct that Intuitionism=/=Constructivism, but c’mon. You have to know that assuming an empty type exists is just assuming the Principle of Explosion is true.

@PW_246  The BHK interpretation has not to do with what I said, constructive =/= intuitionistic.  Rather, your "is just" should be a "corresponds to": what is at play here is Curry-Howard.

The BHK interpretation for implication is just a mathematical formalism capturing the notion you presented.
